# implement content edge insets button android

Tags: android

This is rather tough for me. I am trying to implement the content edge insets feature found in the ios for android button. I believe this enables positioning of the content inside the button based on top, bottom, left and right values. Does anyone have a clue?

Comment: I am desperate. Any suggestions are welcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the attributes:

```
android:paddingTop
android:paddingBottom
android:paddingLeft
android:paddingRight
```

This controls the amount of 'empty' space between the border of the button and the text.

Comment: I would like some more details please..An example perhaps